# Why do I have to use cartesian coordinates in a perspective projection?

Tags: gps, transformation, perspectivecamera, cartesian-coordinates

In any tutorial is written, that cartesian coordinates are necessary for a perspective projection.

Let's say I have the position of camera and object in spherical coordinates (Longitude, Latitude, Altitude). Why do I have to transform them to cartesian coordinates? Is it possible to calculate the projection with my spherical coordinates?

Thanks